# Magento 2.2.3 - Remove price from select field on product page

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2.3, select, option

I was trying to remove the price which Magento adds to the options in a Select field but can't seem to get rid of the price. From what I could find on the internet it should be edited on the following location: **app\code\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php**

At **rule 62**

```
$_value->getTitle() . ' ' . strip_tags($priceStr) . '',
```

And the following bit at **rule 170 - 173**

```
$_value->getTitle() .
'</span> ' .
$priceStr .
'</label>';
```

I changed these but the price still shows up in the select field as can be seen on the Image below.
[image]

Does anyone know where I can change this?

Comment: You need to override that Class using di.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a JS solution which removes the price from the option. This function fires when the select changes which occurs when the price is added to the option field. It then checks each option for "+€" and "-€" this could be any currency however. It then removes everything from this sign so it returns the option without the price behind it.

```
$('select.product-custom-option').change(function(){
    $('option').each(function(){
        var selectedOption = $(this).text();
        if (selectedOption.indexOf('+€') > -1) {
            selectedOption = selectedOption.substring(0, selectedOption.indexOf('+€'));
            $(this).text(selectedOption);
        } else if (selectedOption.indexOf('-€') > -1) {
            selectedOption = selectedOption.substring(0, selectedOption.indexOf('-€'));
            $(this).text(selectedOption);
        }
    });     
});
```

The result:

[image: The result]

Comment: Follow-up question by a new user here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239650/https-magento-stackexchange-com-questions-236276-magento-2-2-3-remove-price-fr

Comment: I am using this solution, it also remove the "--Please select--" text, Any help?

Answer (score 5):

**This is an update for Magento 2.2 and 2.3** --- the proper way to remove this is to override a JavaScript file into the active theme, and remove a section of code

The culprit is

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js - line 415

```
// vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js
// ... Line 415 on Magento 2.2.x, 2.3.x

if (optionPriceDiff !== 0) {
    options[i].label = options[i].label + ' ' + priceUtils.formatPrice(
        optionPriceDiff,
        this.options.priceFormat,
        true);
}
// ...
```

Commenting out the above code block will remove the price increase without the need to add an additional binding onto the page.

Full article here: https://www.cadence-labs.com/2019/07/magento-2-remove-price-from-select-dropdown-on/

**EDIT - 8th June 2020:**
The lines to comment out for Magento 2.3.5 are lines 460 - 466.

Comment: this man F**ks! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I found an easier solution for this:

In configurable.js in your element.options you already have the option label without price:
[image]

As you can see, you just have to use the **initialLabel** instead of **label**.
So create a mixin as said above:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/configurable': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And in your mixin just change the output of the _getOptionLabel function to **initialLabel**:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('mage.configurable', widget, {
            _getOptionLabel: function (option) {
                return option.initialLabel;
            }
        });
        return $.mage.configurable;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to hide the "+price" from dropdown

I've just edited

> pub/static/frontend/(vendor)/(theme)/(Language)/Magento_Catalog/js/price-options.js

```
var globalOptions = {
    productId: null,
    priceHolderSelector: '.price-box', //data-role="priceBox"
    optionsSelector: '.product-custom-option',
    optionConfig: {},
    optionHandlers: {},
    optionTemplate: '<%= data.label %>' 

    /*edited +
    '<% if (data.finalPrice.value) { %>' +
    ' +<%- data.finalPrice.formatted %>' +
    '<% } %>'
    edited*/,

    controlContainer: 'dd'
};
```

Then "php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush"

Many thanks to the analysts who pointed out other answers.

Comment: This might temporarily solve it but when you refresh the static content you have to change it again.

Answer (score 2):

Better than completely overwriting `/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` would be a small [JS mixin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html):

In your custom module, create these two files:

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/configurable': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js`

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * This mixin removes the price increase labels from configurable attribute dropdown options,
     * if the attribute code equals "my_attribute_code".
     *
     * Example:
     *   "Foo +5,00 €" => "Foo"
     */
    var configurableWidgetMixin = {
        _fillSelect: function (element) {
            var _result = this._super(element);

            // optionally check for an attribute code if you don't want to hide prices for all attribute dropdowns
            if (element.config.code === 'my_attribute_code') {
                if (element.options) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < element.options.length; i++) {
                        element.options[i].label = element.options[i].label.replace(/^(.*)(\s[+-][\d,]+\s€)$/, '$1');
                    }
                }
            }

            return _result;
        }
    };

    return function (targetWidget) {
        $.widget('mage.configurable', targetWidget, configurableWidgetMixin); // the widget alias should be like for the target widget
        return $.mage.configurable; //  the widget by parent alias should be returned
    };
});
```

This is tested with Magento 2.3.5
You should customize the Regex so that it suits your needs. With some improvement, this could also be made a bit locale agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own module and can manage to work by following code:

Add the below code to your **di.xml**. Location of di.xml will:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
</config>
```

Create one file **Select.php** at below location:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

Content of **Select.php**:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;

/**
 * Product options text type block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select
{
    /**
     * Return html for control element
     *
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function getValuesHtml()
    {
        $_option = $this->getOption();
        $configValue = $this->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $_option->getId());
        $store = $this->getProduct()->getStore();

        $this->setSkipJsReloadPrice(1);
        // Remove inline prototype onclick and onchange events

        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN ||
            $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE
        ) {
            $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
            $extraParams = '';
            $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select::class
            )->setData(
                [
                    'id' => 'select_' . $_option->getId(),
                    'class' => $require . ' product-custom-option admin__control-select'
                ]
            );
            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getId() . ']')->addOption('', __('-- Please Select --'));
            } else {
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getId() . '][]');
                $select->setClass('multiselect admin__control-multiselect' . $require . ' product-custom-option');
            }
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(
                    [
                        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    ],
                    false
                );
                $select->addOption(
                    $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                    $_value->getTitle(),
                    ['price' => $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false)]
                );
            }
            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE) {
                $extraParams = ' multiple="multiple"';
            }
            if (!$this->getSkipJsReloadPrice()) {
                $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"';
            }
            $extraParams .= ' data-selector="' . $select->getName() . '"';
            $select->setExtraParams($extraParams);

            if ($configValue) {
                $select->setValue($configValue);
            }

            return $select->getHtml();
        }

        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO ||
            $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX
        ) {
            $selectHtml = '<div class="options-list nested" id="options-' . $_option->getId() . '-list">';
            $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
            $arraySign = '';
            switch ($_option->getType()) {
                case \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO:
                    $type = 'radio';
                    $class = 'radio admin__control-radio';
                    if (!$_option->getIsRequire()) {
                        $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option">' .
                            '<input type="radio" id="options_' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            '" class="' .
                            $class .
                            ' product-custom-option" name="options[' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            ']"' .
                            ' data-selector="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']"' .
                            ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                            ' value="" checked="checked" /><label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            '"><span>' .
                            __('None') . '</span></label></div>';
                    }
                    break;
                case \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                    $type = 'checkbox';
                    $class = 'checkbox admin__control-checkbox';
                    $arraySign = '[]';
                    break;
            }
            $count = 1;
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $count++;

                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(
                    [
                        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    ]
                );

                $htmlValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
                if ($arraySign) {
                    $checked = is_array($configValue) && in_array($htmlValue, $configValue) ? 'checked' : '';
                } else {
                    $checked = $configValue == $htmlValue ? 'checked' : '';
                }

                $dataSelector = 'options[' . $_option->getId() . ']';
                if ($arraySign) {
                    $dataSelector .= '[' . $htmlValue . ']';
                }

                $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option' .
                    $require .
                    '">' .
                    '<input type="' .
                    $type .
                    '" class="' .
                    $class .
                    ' ' .
                    $require .
                    ' product-custom-option"' .
                    ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                    ' name="options[' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    ']' .
                    $arraySign .
                    '" id="options_' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    '_' .
                    $count .
                    '" value="' .
                    $htmlValue .
                    '" ' .
                    $checked .
                    ' data-selector="' . $dataSelector . '"' .
                    ' price="' .
                    $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) .
                    '" />' .
                    '<label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    '_' .
                    $count .
                    '"><span>' .
                    $_value->getTitle() .
                    '</span> ' .
                    //$priceStr .
                    '</label>';
                $selectHtml .= '</div>';
            }
            $selectHtml .= '</div>';

            return $selectHtml;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I created my own module following your code and that part works when I change the code I can make the select field dissappear. However I can still see the price after the option while i commented the $priceStr.

Comment: Could it be that the price is generated somewhere else?

Comment: This is working fine for me for custom options select.

Comment: Okay something else is happening right know, the "option + €0,00" is gone at first but is added a few seconds later. Is there another piece of code somewhere that interferes with this code?

Comment: I think you are using some extension or js which includes it.

Comment: @SukumarGorai How to display $priceStr without including tax ? => https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275252/in-product-detail-page-custom-option-product-options-price-just-display-exclud

Answer (score 1):

This is done via javascript, which is loaded via **vendor/Magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js** file.

In order to change the default behavior, we are going to over-ride the configurable.js file inside your theme.

In my example, I am using the Ultimo theme and have a child theme called custom.

So I create a folder in **app/design/frontend/vendor/<your_theme_name>/<your_vendor_name>/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/** and upload the **vendor/Magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js** file into that folder. The configurable.js file path will be **app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/configurable.js**.

Once that’s done, you can open the configurable file and look for line 415.

You are going to want to comment out line 415 thru 420.

`// if (optionPriceDiff !== 0) {`
`// options[i].label = options[i].label + ' ' + priceUtils.formatPrice(`
`// optionPriceDiff,`
`// this.options.priceFormat,`
`// true);`
`// }`

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a variety of different answers here. This is what I'd do for Magento 2.4.3

Create a Mixin to modify the behaviour of configurable.js that's within vendor/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js

1. Create requirejs-config.js inside custom theme (You can also do this within custom module if you prefer)

Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
                'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

2. Create the Mixin file (Note that the name/location must match as defined in requirejs-config.js - It's a best practise to add -mixin to the end of the file name)

Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/configurable-mixin.js

```
/**
 * Mixin to remove the additional configurable pricing from the select 
   option
 * e.g. red +£50 ---> red
 */
/**
 * @api
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'mage/translate',
    'priceUtils',
    'priceBox',
    'jquery-ui-modules/widget',
    'jquery/jquery.parsequery',
    'fotoramaVideoEvents'
], function ($, _, mageTemplate, $t, priceUtils) {
    'use strict';
    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('mage.configurable', widget, {
            /**
             * Populates an option's selectable choices.
             * @private
             * @param {*} element - Element associated with a configurable option.
             */
            _fillSelect: function (element) {
                var attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, ''),
                    options = this._getAttributeOptions(attributeId),
                    prevConfig,
                    index = 1,
                    allowedProducts,
                    allowedProductsByOption,
                    allowedProductsAll,
                    i,
                    j,
                    finalPrice = parseFloat(this.options.spConfig.prices.finalPrice.amount),
                    optionFinalPrice,
                    optionPriceDiff,
                    optionPrices = this.options.spConfig.optionPrices,
                    allowedOptions = [],
                    indexKey,
                    allowedProductMinPrice,
                    allowedProductsAllMinPrice;

                this._clearSelect(element);
                element.options[0] = new Option('', '');
                element.options[0].innerHTML = this.options.spConfig.chooseText;
                prevConfig = false;

                if (element.prevSetting) {
                    prevConfig = element.prevSetting.options[element.prevSetting.selectedIndex];
                }

                if (options) {
                    for (indexKey in this.options.spConfig.index) {
                        /* eslint-disable max-depth */
                        if (this.options.spConfig.index.hasOwnProperty(indexKey)) {
                            allowedOptions = allowedOptions.concat(_.values(this.options.spConfig.index[indexKey]));
                        }
                    }

                    if (prevConfig) {
                        allowedProductsByOption = {};
                        allowedProductsAll = [];

                        for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                            /* eslint-disable max-depth */
                            for (j = 0; j < options[i].products.length; j++) {
                                // prevConfig.config can be undefined
                                if (prevConfig.config &&
                                    prevConfig.config.allowedProducts &&
                                    prevConfig.config.allowedProducts.indexOf(options[i].products[j]) > -1) {
                                    if (!allowedProductsByOption[i]) {
                                        allowedProductsByOption[i] = [];
                                    }
                                    allowedProductsByOption[i].push(options[i].products[j]);
                                    allowedProductsAll.push(options[i].products[j]);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (typeof allowedProductsAll[0] !== 'undefined' &&
                            typeof optionPrices[allowedProductsAll[0]] !== 'undefined') {
                            allowedProductsAllMinPrice = this._getAllowedProductWithMinPrice(allowedProductsAll);
                            finalPrice = parseFloat(optionPrices[allowedProductsAllMinPrice].finalPrice.amount);
                        }
                    }

                    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                        if (prevConfig && typeof allowedProductsByOption[i] === 'undefined') {
                            continue; //jscs:ignore disallowKeywords
                        }

                        allowedProducts = prevConfig ? allowedProductsByOption[i] : options[i].products.slice(0);
                        optionPriceDiff = 0;

                        if (typeof allowedProducts[0] !== 'undefined' &&
                            typeof optionPrices[allowedProducts[0]] !== 'undefined') {
                            allowedProductMinPrice = this._getAllowedProductWithMinPrice(allowedProducts);
                            optionFinalPrice = parseFloat(optionPrices[allowedProductMinPrice].finalPrice.amount);
                            optionPriceDiff = optionFinalPrice - finalPrice;
                            options[i].label = options[i].initialLabel;
                        }

                        if (allowedProducts.length > 0 || _.include(allowedOptions, options[i].id)) {
                            options[i].allowedProducts = allowedProducts;
                            element.options[index] = new Option(this._getOptionLabel(options[i]), options[i].id);

                            if (typeof options[i].price !== 'undefined') {
                                element.options[index].setAttribute('price', options[i].price);
                            }

                            if (allowedProducts.length === 0) {
                                element.options[index].disabled = true;
                            }

                            element.options[index].config = options[i];
                            index++;
                        }

                        /* eslint-enable max-depth */
                    }
                }
            },
        });

        return $.widget.configurable;
    };
});
```

Here I am simply over-riding the _fillSelect function and removing the following:

```
                if (optionPriceDiff !== 0) {
                    options[i].label += ' ' + priceUtils.formatPrice(
                        optionPriceDiff,
                        this.options.priceFormat,
                        true
                    );
                }
```

You may wish to clean up the defines at the top of this file to remove the ones not used in this specific mixin file, although these are just the ones used in the main configurable.js file.

Comment: This works well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can [Extend JS Function](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html#extend-js-object) `_getOptionLabel`.

`app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js`

```js
define(['jquery', 'mage/utils/wrapper'], function($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function(target) {
        target.prototype._getOptionLabel = wrapper.wrap(target.prototype._getOptionLabel, function(original, option) {
            return option.initialLabel;
        });

        return target;
    };
});
```

`app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```js
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {'VendorName_ModuleName/js/configurable': true},
        },
    },
};
```

---

I made `VCT Price Diff` on Magento Marketplace module that solves this problem.