# Where should this JS go? re: Remove price from select field on product page

Tags: magento2, custom-options

Following up on [Magento 2.2.3 - Remove price from select field on product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236276/magento-2-2-3-remove-price-from-select-field-on-product-page)

From the accepted answer by Remco, where should I put this JS code?

```
$('select.product-custom-option').change(function(){
    $('option').each(function(){
        var selectedOption = $(this).text();
        if (selectedOption.indexOf('+€') > -1) {
            selectedOption = selectedOption.substring(0, selectedOption.indexOf('+€'));
            $(this).text(selectedOption);
        } else if (selectedOption.indexOf('-€') > -1) {
            selectedOption = selectedOption.substring(0, selectedOption.indexOf('-€'));
            $(this).text(selectedOption);
        }
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add your custom js in the product view page using the following layout file.

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="js/custom.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Now you can add your js code in the following file.

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/js/custom.js

```
require(["jquery"], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // add your js code here
        $('select.product-custom-option').change(function(){
            $('option').each(function(){
                var selectedOption = $(this).text();
                if (selectedOption.indexOf('+€') > -1) {
                    selectedOption = selectedOption.substring(0, selectedOption.indexOf('+€'));
                    $(this).text(selectedOption);
                } else if (selectedOption.indexOf('-€') > -1) {
                    selectedOption = selectedOption.substring(0, selectedOption.indexOf('-€'));
                    $(this).text(selectedOption);
                }
            });     
        });

    });
});
```

Don't forget to run the deploy command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Tried to put and edit, I made it.
But my knowledge of "js" is too small, and the js is breaking because the first '$' is getting null all function.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: I am trying to remove price field from choose option dropdown but the above one doesn't work.

Comment: @chanchal Create a separate post and ask your question there so others can also help you.