# How to remove price from configurable products drop down options in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, dropdown-attribute

I have configurable products made with multiple simple products on my magento 2.3.3 site.
I have one attribute called Product lenght which consists of Yards and Swatch option.
In the dropdown along with these options it also shows the price of the product.
See https://prnt.sc/v6t1b6
Can any one tell me how to remove this price and show only Yards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2.2.3 - Remove price from select field on product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236276/magento-2-2-3-remove-price-from-select-field-on-product-page)

Comment: Try This [Hide Price](https://www.cadence-labs.com/2019/07/magento-2-remove-price-from-select-dropdown-on/)